# Process a stream of sessions on aws

Tags: aws-lambda, apache-flink

Is there a way to implement somethong like Flink's session-window on aws with lambda and some way of managing messages?

We have a stream of small events with a session id. We cannot guarantee the order of the arriving events and we don't always have a session-finished event. We know that session ids are unique. We also know that when a session is finished it won't be restarted. We also know that when the session is active we will receive a message every minute or so. We need to process the entire session as a whole.
We want to wait for a silent time of X minutes, and if no messages arrive we will process the entire session as a whole.
This is exactly what Flink's silent window does, is there a way to do the same thing purely using aws lambda and it's triggers?

There can be 10s of millions of sessions at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with an AWS Lambda.

Lambdas are stateless, they are able to process messages one by one, but cannot offer any processing over a sequence of messages, which would be required for the kind of windowing logic you describe.

Maybe an option for you would be Kinesis Data Analytics? Under the hood, this one is actually Flink, although it's provided as a managed service by AWS, so maybe you'll get there the "lambda-like" experience you're looking for?

Comment: Yes I know that Lambdas are stateless, the state could be stored on s3 though or some other queues. I'll look into Kinesis to see if it allows to implement some kind of session window to process by lambda

Comment: Hi Slava. Thanks for the feed-back. AWS has 2 distinct products that are called "Kinesis" (which is probably just a marketing move to make it "all look like one thing"). Kinesis Data Analytics is about compute, it's a competitor to Spark Streaming, Kafka Streams or Flink as offered by other vendors. Kinesis Data Stream, on the other hand, is about storage, it's a competitor to Kafka brokers or Apache Pulsar. For the use case you described, I would avoid Lambda and use something like Flink, Kinesis Data Analytics (which is Flink under the hood), Kafka Streams,... or some similar framework

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into the 'Kinesis' products family, and you are right, Kinesis Data Analytics is exactly what we need for this specific usecase. We will group the data into a session and once it's finished we will probably invoke Lambda to process the entire session. From what I understood, Lambda scales much quicker on load peaks than Kinesis Data Analytics. We also would want different types of lambdas to process different types of sessions. So instead of forking inside the code, we will fork based on lambda. This will allow us adding more types of Lambdas without changing existing code